# ANOVA in science social

Tags: anova, statistical-test, manova

I want to know if I can applied the test of ANOVA in my data:
the items are scaled from 1 to 4,
the Dimension is the sum of the items,
the last variable is the region.
I want to applied the test anova to see if there is an impact of region on the dimension:

| item1 | item2 | item3 | item4 | dimension | region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 6 | CH |
| 2 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 8 | DA |
| 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 14 | CH |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 11 | CH |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 10 | CH |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 9 | DA |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 9 | FA |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 9 | FA |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 6 | DA |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 12 | FA |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 13 | CH |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 9 | CH |

statistically confused about if I can applied Anova in this case even the pre tests as normalilty is not valid